# Json data doubles on reload

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have developed a REST API for my Android app which consists of data related to various courses.

I have developed it using Spring Boot and run on my local server. At first it works fine. But the problem is the data keeps doubling when I reload the page. I know its something related to Array List or something which I am using in project, but cannot find solution.

At first I got this:

[image: This]

which is okay. Then when I reload the page I got this:

[image: This]

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. However i have resolved it. I have created the Array List object outside of the method rather than inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created the Array List object outside of the method rather than inside then in the first line of the method write the code :

```
arrayListObject.clear();
```